# How to create a migration file dynamically from library in rails 4.0

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How to create a `migration file` dynamically in rails 4.0?

I want to add some columns to different tables dynamically via my library module. There would be a method that create a migration file and add content to it.

How can I create it from a library?

Comment: Please read the Qn carefully. I specified here how to create a 'Migration File' not 'Migration', and someone down voted my answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, I found a way to adding a migration file from lib. I created a method for this. The following code snippet shows the methods we use and gives a better idea to create migration file dynamically.

```
 def create_columns(tb_with_cols)
    add_columns = ""
    tb_name = tb_with_cols.keys.first
    columns = tb_with_cols.values.first
    columns.each { |c_name, c_type| add_columns << "\tadd_column(':#{tb_name}', :#{c_name}, :#{c_type})\n" }

    add_columns
 end

 def migration_file_content(tb_with_cols)
   cols = create_columns(tb_with_cols)
<<-RUBY
  class AddMissingColumnsToTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
     def change_table
    #{cols}
   end
 end
  RUBY
 end


 def write_content_to_file(path, content)
    File.open(path, 'w+') do |f|
      f.write(content)
    end
 end
```

Just call the method `migration_file_content` in your code. Pass the parameter `tb_with_cols` as a Hash, in which the key is the `table_name` and value is the `columns` that should be added to that table. Ex:

```
tb_with_cols = {:users => {:name => :string, :age => :integer, :address => :text} }
content = migration_file_content(tb_with_cols)
write_content_to_file("#{Rails.root}/db/migrations/', content)
```

After that call the method `write_content_to_file` with your new migration file path and the content from our `migration_file_content` method.